# Increase the width of a column in SharePoint 2013 List

Tags: list, sharepoint-server, css, column

How can I increase the width of a column in SharePoint 2013 list, without increasing the entire width of the page.

Such that the if **Column 4** width is increased it squeezes the other column to allocate space, but not increase the entire webpage width.

Yes it can be done with **CSS** and I have tried increasing the value of the column.

**CSS Code:**

```
.ms-listviewtable tr:first-child td +td+td+td
{

width:600px;

}
```

But on screen it doesn't increase the width of column 4, but of any other column and it is confusing.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Can this be done without code? Using the editing tools within SharePoint? I do not have the tools or knowledge to use any code?

Answer (score 4):

You can set the webpart to a static width and then set the width of any column that you like with a script editor webpart.

```
<style type='text/css'>
.ms-vh-div[DisplayName='<ColumnName>']
{
  width:250px;
}
</style>
```

Just insert the display name of the column instead of `<ColumnName>`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below css:

```
.ms-listviewtable td:nth-child(4) {
    width:600px;
}
```

Here, in `nth-child()` you have to pass **number of column**. Here it's for 4th column.

And if its width cannot be overridden then use `width:600px !important;` in upper code.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("TH.ms-vh2:contains('Column Name')").css("width", "300px"); //You can change the Column Name to be the column you want to change the width, Title in the code for example.
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me was very simply. As soon as multiple [Space]s are not working because are shortened by design, I extended the name of column in setting by using char from ASCII like that: **[ALT]+255**. It is an invisible char. You can write **as many chars as you wish** in the tittle of the column and it will **make it wider** without shortening.